# Get the image title and put before a tag

Tags: jquery

tht's my html code coming like that

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="" href="33.jpg">
        <img style="opacity: 0.7;" title="<a href='http://www.abc.com.au/13.html' >Cosmo Bride - Spring 2013</a>" src="33.jpg" class="image" height="200" width="150">
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="" href="29.jpg">
        <img style="opacity: 0.7;" title="<a href='http://www.abc.com.au/br.html' >Bazaar </a>" src="9.jpg" class="image">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I m getting every image title with below code

```
jQuery('img.image').each( function(idx,img) {
    pTitle = img.title;

});
```

But i need result like that

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <a href='http://www.abc.com.au/13.html' >Cosmo Bride - Spring 2013</a>
            <a class="" href="33.jpg">
            <img style="opacity: 0.7;" title="<a href='http://www.abc.com.au/13.html' >Cosmo Bride - Spring 2013</a>" src="33.jpg" class="image" height="200" width="150">
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
           <a href='http://www.abc.com.au/br.html' >Bazaar </a>
            <a class="" href="29.jpg">
            <img style="opacity: 0.7;" title="<a href='http://www.abc.com.au/br.html' >Bazaar </a>" src="9.jpg" class="image">
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/):

```
jQuery('img.image').each( function(idx,img) {
    var pTitle = img.title,
        $this = $(this);
    $(pTitle).insertBefore($this.parent());
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2VkXg/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't write html code as attribute value ( img title here ) because it will break on single and double quotes.

but you can add the anchor ( ptitle here ) as hidden anchor and then display it and move it elsewhere using jQuery